# MS SQL Server: Import Flat File with auto-increment ID

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, csv, auto-increment

So I've downloaded a sample database. It originally didn't have an ID column so I inserted one in through Excel. Anyways, I went through `DatabaseName > Tasks > Import Flat File` and the usual process, and arrive at the modify columns below.

[image: Import Flat File Wizard]

My issue is, where can I specify that the ID column should be auto-incremented? And if I can't do that here, what should I do as a workaround?

Comment: I think you need to create the table with the auto-increment ID outside of the import wizard.  But I'm not clear on your needs, is the ID coming from your flat file, or do you want SQL to generate it?

Comment: @JonathanFite Either one is fine tbh, I just need an auto-incrementing ID with the data from the flat file (I generally prefer integer ID's over strings). The table in my flat .csv file contains ID for its 500 people, numbered from 1 - 500. I want 501 to be added by default when I add a new row somehow. I'm kind of new to SQL so I wouldn't know if it's possible to create a table with autoincrement ID, then import the data from the CSV file. If it is, I'd likely resort to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter a column to be an IDENTITY column.

What you'll need to do is create a new column which is defined as an IDENTITY.

Then use an update statement to update the new column from the old one (with SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON before and OFF after the update).

Once this is done, drop the old column.

Fianlly, rename the new one to the old name.

Comment: Okay... Let me test this. If it works, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: It works... but now SQL won't let me move that new column to the first column on the table lol. Either way, you did solve the problem.

Comment: Usually, that should not be a big deal if the column is not "placed" at the start as you should specify column name in the select or update (as a best practice).
If you want it as the first, then I guess you'll need to create your table first (with the identity) and then load it from the csv